Google Data API: How to replicate GA4 Pages and Screens report?
In Google Analytics 4 the built-in report "Pages and Screens" allows for Views to be reported when a specific Event name is selected as a filter.
GA4 Reports > Engagement > Pages and Screens example
How do I replicate result this using a query to Data API?
When attempting to replicate a similar query with Google's Data API (example is PHP) the Views are reported as zero values once a filter is applied for a specific Event name.
$request = (new RunReportRequest())
->setProperty('properties/' . $propertyId)
->setDimensions(
    [new Dimension(['name' => 'unifiedPagePathScreen'])],
    [new Dimension(['name' => 'eventName'])])
->setMetrics([
    new Metric(['name' => 'screenPageViews']),
    new Metric(['name' => 'eventCount'])
])
->setDateRanges([
    new DateRange([
        'start_date' => '2024-01-1',
        'end_date' => 'today',
    ])
])
->setDimensionFilter(new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'eventName',
        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
            'value' => 'file_download'
        ]),
    ]),
]));


The above API request (PHP) will return correct counts for the specified Event, but the Views will be zero. If the filter for the Event is removed then the Views values are once again reported correctly.
No doubt I'm doing wrong, as I'm fairly new to using the Data API. Any help would be appreciated.
